# NIntegrate user defined function

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have the the function

```
f[a_] := Module[{solution, ans, x}, solution = NSolve[x + a == 4];
```

I want to integrate it by writing

```
NIntegrate[f[x],{x,1,5}
```

but I get this error message:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand x$2682 has evaluated to non-numerical values 
for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1,5}}.
```

In my problem the function is a bit more complicated but the principle is the same. Is there a nice way to integrate user defined equation-solving functions using for instance NIntegrate? I am aware that you can use f[x] to generate a table, interpolate the table, and finally integrate. However, is there perhaps a nicer way of doing this that avoids creating a interpolating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `f[a]` doesn't return a value!

Try (thanks @SjoerdSmit for his helpful comment)

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := Block[{x}, x /. NSolve[x + a == 4, x][[1]]];
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 5}]
(*4*)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I have a further question. If I write f[a_] := Module[{solution, ans,x}, solution = NSolve[x + a == 4]; ans = x /. solution; ans[[1]]]. Then my function returns a value, but I still get the same error as before. What is the difference between what I do now, and what you do?

Comment: @MOOSE This answer is not correct. The integral should return 4; not 8. `f[x]` Inside `NIntegrate` evaluates prematurely to `2.` (by solving `x + x == 4`) and is integrated afterwards. If you change `x` to `b` in `NIntegrate` you get a different answer because of this. The correct way to do this, is to use the pattern `f[a_?NumericQ] := ...` to prevent premature evaluation of `f`.

Comment: @MOOSE And upon further investigation, it's also recommended to localize `x` in `f` (like you did) because the evaluation can leak otherwise.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks for your hint, I modified my answer!

Answer (score 0):

your module definition is not correct, is this what you are looking for?

```
f[a_] := Module[{solution}, solution = NSolve[x + a - 4 == 0]; 
  Return[solution]]
f[5]
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps its the mondays. How is my module definition not correct? If I write f[1] it returns 3.

Comment: There is one `]` missing in the module and what is `ans` and `x` in your module  definition?